# Der Wind dreht auf Südost

Tags: meaning, phrase

Does that mean that

- the wind will be *coming from* south-east (since wind direction is usually reported by the direction from which it originates)

or that

- the wind will be *blowing to* south-east (which is how I'd intuitively interpret "auf")?

Comment: I agree that it is a confusing way to phrase it :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In German the wind direction [(*"Windrichtung"*)](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windrichtung) is described in the same way as in English. In both languages the direction given is the direction the wind comes **from**.

> Der Wind bläst aus Südost. Wir haben Südostwind.

In your example however we see the verb *"[drehen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/drehen#Bedeutung1d)"* with the preposition *"auf"*. This indicates there was a **change** of wind direction but still the direction is where the wind comes **from**:

> Der Wind drehte auf Südost. Zuvor hatten wir Ostwind.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it means that the wind comes from south-east. Here are some other alternatives to say from where the wind comes.

> Der Wind weht meist schwach aus südlichen Richtungen.
>
> Der Wind weht mäßig aus Südost bis Südwest.
>
> Der Wind weht schwach bis mäßig um Südost.
>
> Der schwache Wind kommt aus Süd.
>
> Böig auffrischender Südwestwind.
>
> Die Wolken ziehen vom Südwesten über Deutschland hinein.
>
> Der südöstliche Wind weht meist schwach.
>
> **Der Wind dreht von Südost auf Südwest.**